# TestNG doesn't preserve the order when dependsOnMethods is specified

Tags: java, testng

In case that we want to preserve the order of the execution on class level and on the other hand we want to use the option "dependsOnMethods" and "parallel="false"", things get unexpected. Tested with TestNG 6.8.8 to 6.11. Similar behaviour is described here:

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1291

I've tried all available options provided by TestNG and the only thing that worked for me is to set all test classes (which contains "dependsOnGroups") in their own  tag in the testng.xml config. But that leads to another issue. We are using also "dependsOnGroups" which is not visible between separately defined tests (i.e. different  tags). Which I've to workaround in a TestNG Listener and using the "ignoreMissingDependencies = true", by checking the dependency chain for any failures of dependent group.

Note: I've tried "group-by-instances="true"" and other TestNG tweaks like priority and threadCount, forkCount, etc. without any success.

Here is a snippet of what we have, that is working for the moment. Of course I'm open for any suggestions that could help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite verbose="0" name="Regretion Suite" parallel="false"
    preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Tests without dependsOnMethods" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.demo.testng.TestSetup" />
            <class name="com.demo.testng.TestOne" />
            <class name="com.demo.testng.TestTwo" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TestThree with dependsOnMethods">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.demo.testng.TestThree" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TestFour with dependsOnMethods">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.demo.testng.TestFour" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Command line suite -->

package com.demo.testng;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
@Listeners(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class)
@Test(groups = {"Setup"})
public class TestSetup
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestSetup.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        log.info("TestSetup:oneTimeSetUp");
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void oneTimeCleanUp()
    {
        log.info("TestSetup::oneTimeCleanUp");
    }


    @Test
    public void testOne()
    {
        log.info("TestSetup::testOne");
    }


    @Test
    public void testTwo()
    {
        log.info("TestSetup::testTwo");
    }


    @Test
    public void testThree()
    {
        log.info("TestSetup::testThree");
    }
}

package com.demo.testng;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
@Listeners(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class)
@Test(groups = {"Execution"}, dependsOnGroups = {"Setup"}, ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
public class TestOne
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestOne.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        log.info("TestOne::oneTimeSetUp");
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void oneTimeCleanUp()
    {
        log.info("TestOne::oneTimeCleanUp");
    }


    @Test
    public void testOne()
    {
        log.info("TestOne::testOne");
    }


    @Test
    public void testTwo()
    {
        log.info("TestOne::testTwo");
    }


    @Test
    public void testThree()
    {
        log.info("TestOne::testThree");
    }
}

package com.demo.testng;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
@Listeners(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class)
@Test(groups = {"Execution"}, dependsOnGroups = {"Setup"}, ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
public class TestTwo
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestTwo.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        log.info("TestTwo::oneTimeSetUp");
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void oneTimeCleanUp()
    {
        log.info("TestTwo::oneTimeCleanUp");
    }


    @Test
    public void testOne()
    {
        log.info("TestTwo::testOne");
    }


    @Test
    public void testTwo()
    {
        log.info("TestTwo::testTwo");
    }


    @Test
    public void testThree()
    {
        log.info("TestTwo::testThree");
    }
}

package com.demo.testng;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
@Listeners(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class)
@Test(groups = {"Execution"}, dependsOnGroups = {"Setup"}, ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
public class TestThree
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestThree.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        log.info("TestThree::oneTimeSetUp");
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void oneTimeCleanUp()
    {
        log.info("TestThree::oneTimeCleanUp");
    }


    @Test(ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testOne() throws InterruptedException
    {
        log.info("TestThree::testOne");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }


    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testOne", ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testTwo()
    {
        log.info("TestThree::testTwo");
    }


    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testTwo", ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testThree()
    {
        log.info("TestThree::testThree");
    }
}

package com.demo.testng;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
@Listeners(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class)
@Test(groups = {"Execution"}, dependsOnGroups = {"Setup"}, ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
public class TestFour
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestFour.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        log.info("TestFour::oneTimeSetUp");
    }


    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void oneTimeCleanUp()
    {
        log.info("TestFour::oneTimeCleanUp");
    }


    @Test(ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testOne()
    {
        log.info("TestFour::testOne");
    }


    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testOne", ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testTwo() throws InterruptedException
    {
        log.info("TestFour::testTwo");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }


    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testTwo", ignoreMissingDependencies = true)
    public void testThree()
    {
        log.info("TestFour::testThree");
    }
}

package com.demo.testng;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.IConfigurationListener2;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.seeburger.test.api.util.TestNGWatcher;


/**
 * @author a.kolev
 */
public class StateVerifierTestNGWatcher extends TestNGWatcher implements IConfigurationListener2
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StateVerifierTestNGWatcher.class);

    private static final String CONFIGURATION_METHOD = "oneTimeSetUp";
    private static final String CLEANUP_METHOD = "oneTimeCleanUp";
    private static Set<String> failedGroups = new HashSet<>();


    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result)
    {
        checkDependencyConditions(result);
    }


    /**
     * @param result
     */
    private void checkDependencyConditions(ITestResult result)
    {
        String[] groupsDependedUpon = result.getMethod().getGroupsDependedUpon();
        for (String groupDependedUpon : groupsDependedUpon)
        {
            skipIfDependencyFound(groupDependedUpon);
        }

        super.onTestStart(result);
    }


    /**
     * @param groupDependedUpon
     */
    private void skipIfDependencyFound(String groupDependedUpon)
    {
        if (failedGroups.contains(groupDependedUpon))
        {
            throw new SkipException("Setup phase failed!");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
    {
        String[] groups = result.getMethod().getGroups();

        for (int i = failedGroups.size(); i < groups.length; i++)
        {
            failedGroups.add(groups[i]);
        }

        super.onTestFailure(result);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult itr)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult itr)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult itr)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void beforeConfiguration(ITestResult tr)
    {
        if (tr.getMethod().getMethodName().equals(CONFIGURATION_METHOD) || tr.getMethod().getMethodName().equals(CLEANUP_METHOD))
        {
            checkConfigMethodDependencyConditions(tr);
        }
        else
        {
            checkDependencyConditions(tr);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param tr
     */
    private void checkConfigMethodDependencyConditions(ITestResult tr)
    {
        Class< ? extends Object> instanceClass = tr.getInstance().getClass();
        if (instanceClass != null)
        {
            Test[] annotationsByType = instanceClass.getAnnotationsByType(Test.class);
            if (annotationsByType.length > 0)
            {
                String[] dependsOnGroups = annotationsByType[0].dependsOnGroups();
                for (String groupDependedUpon : dependsOnGroups)
                {
                    skipIfDependencyFound(groupDependedUpon);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log.warn(String.format("Configuration method %s instance class is null! Configuration method is not checked for failed dependency groups!", CONFIGURATION_METHOD));
        }

    }
}
```

Here is what is the expected result and what is the real one:

Without workaround result:

```
TestSetup:oneTimeSetUp
TestSetup::testOne
TestSetup::testThree
TestSetup::testTwo
TestSetup::oneTimeCleanUp

TestOne::oneTimeSetUp
TestOne::testOne
TestOne::testThree
TestOne::testTwo
TestOne::oneTimeCleanUp

TestTwo::oneTimeSetUp
TestTwo::testOne
TestTwo::testThree
TestTwo::testTwo
TestTwo::oneTimeCleanUp

TestThree::oneTimeSetUp
TestThree::testOne
TestThree::testTwo
TestFour::oneTimeSetUp
TestFour::testOne
TestThree::testThree
TestThree::oneTimeCleanUp
TestFour::testTwo
TestFour::testThree
TestFour::oneTimeCleanUp
```

Expected result:

```
TestSetup:oneTimeSetUp
TestSetup::testOne
TestSetup::testThree
TestSetup::testTwo
TestSetup::oneTimeCleanUp

TestOne::oneTimeSetUp
TestOne::testOne
TestOne::testThree
TestOne::testTwo
TestOne::oneTimeCleanUp

TestTwo::oneTimeSetUp
TestTwo::testOne
TestTwo::testThree
TestTwo::testTwo
TestTwo::oneTimeCleanUp

TestThree::oneTimeSetUp
TestThree::testOne
TestThree::testTwo
TestThree::testThree
TestThree::oneTimeCleanUp

TestFour::oneTimeSetUp
TestFour::testOne
TestFour::testTwo
TestFour::testThree
TestFour::oneTimeCleanUp
```